# Execute command in different directories

Tags: maven, unix

I have a requirement where i need to change the pom version of some projects and following steps will be involved:

1. Search for all the projects whose pom is having a particular version say "1".
2. Now navigate to all these projects directory one by one and execute maven command to update version one by one.

So far i have been able to get list of all projects using following command:

```
find . -name "pom.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il '1'
```

Now i need to execute maven command `'mvn versions:update-parent'` in directory of each of pom's found above.

Can this be done in a single command?

Edit:

If yes then how to go about it?

Comment: yes, it can be done in a single command.

Comment: @yaccz: It will be very helpful if you can give me that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this, seems to work.  Run 'mvn clean' in the directory of any pom containing 1.8.6:

```
find . -name 'pom.xml' -print0 \
  | xargs -0 grep -l '1.8.6' \
  | xargs -I XX find . -path XX -execdir mvn clean \;
```